# How to use go template to parse html files with FuncMap

Tags: parsing, templates, dictionary, go, func

I use following code to parse html template. It works well.

```
func test(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    data := struct {A int B int }{A: 2, B: 3}

    t := template.New("test.html").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"add": add})

    t, err := t.ParseFiles("test.html")

    if err!=nil{
        log.Println(err)
    }
    t.Execute(w, data)
}

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

and html template test.html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="{{add .A .B}}">
</body>
</html>
```

But when I move html file to another directory. Then use the following code. The output is always empty.

```
t := template.New("./templates/test.html").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"add": add})

t, err := t.ParseFiles("./templates/test.html")
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Or html/template package can not be used like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that your program (the `html/template` package) can't find the `test.html` file. When you specify relative paths (yours are relative), they are resolved to the current working directory.

You have to make sure the html files/templates are in the right place. If you start your app with `go run ...` for example, relative paths are resolved to the folder you're in, that will be the working directory.

This relative path: `"./templates/test.html"` will try to parse the file being in the `templates` subfolder of the current folder. Make sure it's there.

Another option is to use absolute paths.

**And also another important note:** Do not parse templates in your handler function! That runs to serve each incoming request. Instead parse them in the package `init()` functions once.

More details on this:

[It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p)

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question. Because I mixed the parameter of template.New(name string) and t.ParseFiles(filenames...string).  It should be template.New(filename string).