# No such file or directory error in golang

Tags: go

I want to specify an html template in one of my golang controller
My directory structure is like this

```
 Project
 -com
  -src
   - controller
     -contoller.go
 -view
  - html
   -first.html
```

I want to load first.html for request /new .I have used NewHandler for url /new and the NewHandler func is executing when /new request comes and is in controller.go. Here is my code

```
func NewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("view/html/first.html")
    if err == nil {
        log.Println("Template parsed successfully....")
    }
 err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "view/html/first.html", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Not Found template")
}
//  t.Execute(w, "")
}
```

But I am getting an error

```
     panic: open first.html: no such file or directory
```

Please help me to remove this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use go template to parse html files with FuncMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058772/how-to-use-go-template-to-parse-html-files-with-funcmap) and [404 page not found - Go rendering css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293452/404-page-not-found-go-rendering-css-file); also related: [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved the issue by giving absolute path of the html. For that I created a class in which the html are parsed

```
package htmltemplates

import (
"html/template"
"path/filepath"
)
```

And in the NewHandler method I removed 
     //Templates is used to store all Templates
    var Templates *template.Template

```
func init() {
filePrefix, _ := filepath.Abs("./work/src/Project/view/html/")       // path from the working directory
Templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filePrefix + "/first.html")) 
...
//htmls must be specified here to parse it
}
```

And in the NewHandler I removed first 5 lines and instead gave

```
err := htmltemplates.Templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "first.html", nil)
```

It is now working .But need a better solution if any

Answer (score 1):

Have you included this line in the main function?

```
http.Handle("/view/", http.StripPrefix("/view/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("view"))))
```

view is the name of the directory that has to be specified in FileServer function to allow read/write.(view directory has to be kept in the same directory where your binary is present)

Comment: yes. router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./view/")))

Comment: router is a mux router

Comment: issue solved by giving absolute path. But need a better solution ,if any

Comment: @AkhilSudhakaran Here are your options if you don't want to use absolute path: [options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31059125/1705598)

Comment: I have been using relative path only and it works fine. The problem must be in accessing the directory only(like /view or ./view etc). You can check by  : Start the server, then try to access the view folder from browser, e.g typing localhost:8080/view should show the list of files available. Thanks @icza, good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to give absolute path name i.e instead of this "view/html/first.html",try this

```
 func NewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        t, err := template.ParseFiles("./work/src/Project/view/html/first.html")
        if err == nil {
            log.Println("Template parsed successfully....")
        }
     err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "view/html/first.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Not Found template")
    }
    //  t.Execute(w, "")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, where I just traversed outside the directory without using libraries to find the path or convert them.

1. Using "os" package get the present working directory. Like,

   `import(
   "os"
   )
   your_function(){
   pwd,_ := os.pwd()}`
2. Above snippet will return you the path where your program is trying to find the file.
   Like
   `D:\Golang_Projects\POC\Distributed_Application_Go\cmd\teacherportal`
3. After you're sure what path your program is looking at, use ".." to come outside of that directory. Like,

   `rootTemplate,err := template.ParseFiles("../../teacherportal/students.gohtml")`

Alternative solutions are also there but I found this quite simple to implement.