# Golang, not passing values from HTML

Tags: html, forms, http, go

I am trying to build a simple, two-`Handler` web server. In the first handler, I am pulling values from two fields, a user's first name and last name. In the second handler I am simply stating, `"Hello" (first name, last name)`.

I've put an `fmt.Println`, and it seems that I'm not correctly pulling the info from the first `Handler` back into the Go programming. Where is this going wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Field struct {
    Firstname  string
    Secondname string
}

func RootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Index Template Parse Error: ", err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Index Template Execution Error: ", err)
    }

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", RootHandler) // sets router
    http.HandleFunc("/welcome", WelcomeHandler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil) // set listen port
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}

func WelcomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    Firstname := r.FormValue("Namef")
    Secondname := r.FormValue("Namel")
    fmt.Println(Firstname)

    f := new(Field)
    f.Firstname = Firstname
    f.Secondname = Secondname
    fmt.Println(*f)
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("tmpl/welcome.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Index Template Parse Error: ", err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, &f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Index Template Execution Error: ", err)
    }

}
```

And here is the `index.html` that I'm pulling the two values from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/welcome" method="post">
<p> Welcome! First I will need your full name: </p>
First Name: <input type="text" id="Namef" name="FirstName"><br>
Last Name:  <input type="text" id="Namel" name="LastName" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the server called "demo_form.asp".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you try to get the form values using wrong names.

You have to use the values you used as the `name` attribute in the HTML document, not the `id`!

```
Firstname := r.FormValue("FirstName")
Secondname := r.FormValue("LastName")
```

And this may just be a practice code from your part, but never parse templates in handlers. Parsing templates is a relatively resource-intensive task, you should do that only once, and since templates are safe for concurrent use, you can use a single [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) value from multiple goroutines (serving concurrent requests). See this question for details: [It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p)

Comment: This did help. For clarity, I changed the name of my variables on the declarations. Thank you.